# Lunar angular frequency

Tags: angular-velocity, moon

I have this question from my teacher which quite confuses me.

It asks to calculate lunar angular speed, when we know that the Moon circles Earth in 27.3 day.

Why is number (27.3) significant here? Is this a trick question?

To my understanding the only needed number is 27 days in which the Moon rotates once around its axis. So, ω = 2π / T = 2π / 27 * 24 * 3600 = (whatever number ends up here).

Am I missing something?

Comment: One can only see one side of the Moon from the Earth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: you are missing something. $0.3$, for one thing. The Moon's sidereal rotation speed is $27.321661 \approx 27.3$, so why drop it in the formula?

As hinted in the comments: the lunar rotation period determines its angular speed, but we don't know its rotation period (in the problem statement). Nevertheless, the moon is in a 1:1 tidal resonance with the Earth, so its sidereal rotation period is the same as its orbital period.